# Default syntax in case of conflicting file extensions in the Atom text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atom-editor

In the Atom text editor, when two language packages define syntax and snippets for files with the same file extension, what determines the precedence?

For example, both `language-ruby` and `language-ruby-on-rails` are available by default, as they are included in the so-called Core Package set, and the two packages share the `.rb` file extension.

How can I make sure that Atom will by default treat `.rb` file as, say, `source.ruby.rails` instead of `source.ruby` files in my projects?

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.cson` file you can specify filename regexes and a related grammars, like so:

```
"*":
  "file-types":
    ".rb?$": "source.ruby.rails"
```